# quicksort on doubly-linked list causes bad pointer?

Tags: c, linked-list, quicksort

I was writing this as part of an exercise to understand the various sorting algorithms and to judge what works best in different situations. Because I never really learned them :(

This was my interpretation of wikipedia's pseudocode, with the additional "equal" list added for speed (hopefully). and a couple of other minor additions. My program crashes once the sorting gets towards the end (2 or 3 nodes remaining). The program sorts descending order.

GDB indicates its a bad pointer with the top variable in the while loop. Apparently it didn't have the null pointer at the end of the list. I suspect the quicklist function is fine but its one of the supporting functions causing the problem. I need help spotting what I did wrong

quicksort:

```
void quicksort(NODE **top,NODE **last,int * size)
{
    if((*size)>3)
    {
        NODE *pivot = pop(last);
        *last=0;
        NODE *greater_node=0;int greater=0; NODE * glast=0;
        NODE *equal_node=0;int equal=0;
        NODE *less_node=0;int less=0; NODE * llast=0;
        int pivot_value=pivot->value;
        int value_at=0;
        while(*top)
        {
            value_at=(*top)->value;
            if(value_at>pivot_value)
            {
                push2(&greater_node,pop(top));
                if(!greater) { glast=greater_node; }
                greater++;
            }
            if(value_at<pivot_value)
            {
                push2(&less_node,pop(top));
                if(!less) { llast=less_node; }
                less++;
            }
            else
            {
                push2(&equal_node,pop(top));
                equal++;
            }
        }
        quicksort(&greater_node,&glast,&greater);
        quicksort(&less_node,&llast,&less);
        cat(&equal_node,less_node);
            cat(&pivot,equal_node);
        cat(&greater_node,pivot);
            *top=greater_node;
        *size = greater+less+equal+1;
    }
    else if((*size)==3)
    {
        NODE *a=(*top);
        NODE *b=(*top)->next;
        NODE *c=(*top)->next->next;
        if(a->value<b->value) { swap(&(a->value),&(b->value)); }
        if(b->value<c->value) { swap(&(b->value),&(c->value)); }
        if(a->value<b->value) { swap(&(a->value),&(b->value)); }
    }
    else if((*size)==2)
    {
            if((*top)->value<(*top)->next->value) swap(&((*top)->value),&((*top)->next->value));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of code for one question!

Comment: I know But I didn't want to leave anything important out. You think I should just trim it down to the quicksort function?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't suggesting that you remove the code from the question. All I meant was that asking strangers on the Internet to debug a ton of code for you might not lead to the outcome you want.

Comment: yeah... I think that was the right thing to do here. At least I'll have piece of mind knowing the main function is logically sound.

Comment: Try it with a zero-length list. Then a one-length list. Then a couple two-length-lists. Then a few three-length-lists. Keep going until you find a list that crashes. That's your **minimal repro**. Now write down *on paper* everything -- **everything** -- that the program should do to sort that list.  Now step through the code in the debugger. The point where it does something that is not on your list, that's where the bug is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get as far as the quicksort function itself, but your `pop()` looks suspect. Specifically, if `*top` points to the first element, the

```
        (*top)=(*top)->next;
```

will have wiped out `*top` before you get a chance to do anything useful with it.

My overall advice would be to find the simplest input on which the code malfunctions, and step through your program in a debugger, watching what's happening. This should enable you to pinpoint the exact moment things start deviating from the plan.

An alternative strategy is to come up with a series of unit tests for each function, to test every building block in isolation.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, but its still crashing in the same spot. I got lots of other problems apparently

Comment: It started working after I completely rewrote the pop function, got rid of the shortcuts. explicitly tested each case. back to code school for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to leave things unresolved. IDK if I actually modified the core function compared to the other methods. Specifically the pop function. But I thought I'd post it for completeness.

```
void quicksort(NODE **top,NODE **last,int * size)
{
    if((*size)>3)
    {
        NODE *pivot = pop(last);
        NODE *greater_node=0;int greater=0; NODE * glast=0;
        NODE *equal_node=0;int equal=0;
        NODE *less_node=0;int less=0; NODE * llast=0;
        int pivot_value=pivot->value;
        int value_at=0;
        while(*top)
        {
            value_at=(*top)->value;
            if(value_at>pivot_value)
            {
                push2(&greater_node,pop(top));
                if(!greater) { glast=greater_node; }
                greater++;
            }
            else if(value_at<pivot_value)
            {
                push2(&less_node,pop(top));
                if(!less) { llast=less_node; }
                less++;
            }
            else
            {
                push2(&equal_node,pop(top));
                equal++;
            }
        }
        quicksort(&greater_node,&glast,&greater);
        quicksort(&less_node,&llast,&less);
        if(less) { cat(&equal_node,less_node); }
            cat(&pivot,equal_node);
        cat(&greater_node,pivot);
            *top=greater_node;
        *size = greater+less+equal+1;
    }
    else if((*size)==3)
    {
        NODE *a=(*top);
        NODE *b=(*top)->next;
        NODE *c=(*top)->next->next;
        if(a->value<b->value) { swap(&(a->value),&(b->value)); }
        if(b->value<c->value) { swap(&(b->value),&(c->value)); }
        if(a->value<b->value) { swap(&(a->value),&(b->value)); }
    }
    else if((*size)==2)
    {
        NODE *a=(*top);
        NODE *b=(*top)->next;
        if(a->value<b->value) { swap(&(a->value),&(b->value)); }
        //if((*top)->value<(*top)->next->value) swap(&((*top)->value),&((*top)->next->value));
    }
}
```